# Neated Loop in Java

Tags: java, sequence, nested-loops

I am still a beginner in Java and Im really confused in nested loop and how to handle the rows and columns.

My goal is,

```
enter num: 5

1 10 11 20 21
2 9  12 19 22
3 8  13 18 23
4 7  14 17 24
5 6  15 16 25.
```

This is my code so far,

```
System.out.print("Enter Number: ");  
x = in.nextInt();

for(int a = 0; a < x; a++) //rows
{
    for(int b = 0; b < x; b++) //columns
    {
        if(b % 2 == 0){

        } else{

        }  
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hey, there does not seem to be a question here. With what do you have a problem? What have you tried?

Comment: strange useless `if (b%2==0) {} else {}` code... and `System.out.println();` you will print nothing at that point. You should put what you want to print inside the `println()` parenthesis, e.g. `println(a)`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the relation between the input and output?

Comment: Sorry, on the useless codes cuz I'm really confused right now what should I use as a basis to start, the var of column or the row. Cuz I can't get the pattern 1,8,9,16 if I based it in rows

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Your question can be answered very quickly and easily with your step-debugger. You should always try and solve your problems with a step debugger before coming to StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

To load a matrix into memory:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```